# How use np.take when the indices is an multiD array

Tags: python, numpy

There are two array, a and indices.

a's shape: (g,N), which means there are g group all with N samples.

indices' shape: (q,g), which means there are q class', each of them contains different indices for the g groups to access a's values.

For example,

```
a = [[1 3 7 8]
     [2 4 5 6]] # shape:(2,4), 2 groups with 4 samples 
indices = [[0 1]
           [2 2]] # shape:(2,2), 2 class' with indices to access a for the two groups.
```

I try to use `np.take(a, indices, axis=1)`and get

```
result = [[[1 3]
           [7 7]]

          [[2 4]
          [5 5]]]
```

but that wasn't what I want.
The result I want to get is:

```
result = [[1,4]
          [7,5]]
```

because

```
indices[0] = [0,1] # class 0's indices for the two groups

a[0,0] = 1 
a[1,1] = 4

indices[1] = [2,2] # class 1's indices for the two groups
a[0,2] = 7
a[1,2] = 5
```

Could anyone help? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `take_along_axis`:

```
np.take_along_axis(a.T,indices,0)
# array([[1, 4],
#        [7, 5]])
```